# SpriteKit Questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am new to Xcode and SpriteKit. I have the following queries. Please can someone help me!

1. I am trying to make a game on Xcode. I have a scrolling background. I have made a long background which I want to continuously play on a loop. When the background's dimension was 768X10240 for IPAD (non-retina), my code didn't show the background. However, when i reduced it to 768X2048 and played it on a loop, it did. So, I guess there's nothing wrong with my code. But why isn't a really long background working?
2. Is there a way to stop the "update" method from running, whilst letting some of the SKActions to run? I tried using self.scene.view.paused which stops everything.
3. Is it possible to pause an SKAction half way? Say, suppose its going to run for 5 seconds, and I pause my scene after 2 seconds, and later unpause it. I want the SKAction to begin from where it had stopped, but its not happening. I tried, self.speed = 0
4. Is it possible to do an SKAction on a given position and not on a child node?

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say what you did wrong. Successfully running a background image loop has nothing to do with the size of the image. However, having a very large images is a bad idea as it might increase your memory requirements to an unacceptable level. Consider using smaller images or tiled images using an application like Tiled. Also, use a texture atlas all the time, every time!
2. You cannot stop the `update:` method from running. The update method is what makes SKActions possible.
3. You cannot pause a SKAction once you have started it unless the pause is part of an action sequence of the action. You can stop a SKAction with the command `[self removeActionForKey:@"animation"];` where self is the sprite. Depending on the animation you are running, this might appear to pause the animation.
4. This question makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you. In 4 what I meant was, I want an animation to be played at a certain position on screen. How do i do that?

Comment: The animation is part of your sprite which means you cannot have your sprite in one position and have its animation play in another position. Change the position of your sprite to where you need your animation to play.

Comment: An addition to 1) Your image was just too big. OpenGL ES and Sprite Kit supports textures to a maximum size of 4096x4096px (2048 x 2048 on older devices).

Answer (score 0):

hi dude just go through

sprite kit documentation before creating any game in sprite kit.

1)for scrolling background you are using huge size image just breakdown your image smaller size and save them inside a folder name that folder yourfoldername.atlas sprite kit automatically treated that folder as a texture atlas

2)you cannot stop update loop at least their is no inbulit mehod for this but you can create your own method for it for e.g.

```
 boolean stopGame=FALSE;
 -(void)stopmyGame
{
    stopGame=TRUE;
 }

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
   if(stopGame)
  {
    return;
  }
  //your update code
 }
```

3) yeah its possible to stop a SKAction in midway
  there is two way for that

1) create a SKAction with key

for eg.
      SKAction *moveTo= [SKAction moveToY:1000 duration:0.5];
     [self runAction:up withKey:@"moveTo"];

```
 [self removeActionForKey:@"moveTo"];
```

2) setting object.speed=0;
     where object is your own class extending from sprite kit base class

4) why u need a action on a given position ...:)

5)you can use koboldkit a framework  created on top of sprite kit  have all the things that spritekit don't have

1)Physics Debug Drawing

2) Super-Fast Renderer TMX Read & Write

3)Plug-In Code for Nodes
Many Built-In Behaviors

4)Audio Engine

and full supported koboldkit forum